# The option "filters" does not have a callable "setFilters" ("setfilters") setter method

Tags: php, zend-framework, filter, doctrine-orm, orm

Environment:

```
"require": {
            "php": "5.6",
            "zendframework/zendframework": "2.5.0",
            "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "2.5.1",
            "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "1.0.0",
            "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.9.2",
            "acelaya/zf2-acmailer": "4.*",
            "tasmaniski/zend-params-helper": "^1.0"
        }
```

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Stdlib\Exception\BadMethodCallException' with message 'The option "filters" does not have a callable "setFilters" ("setfilters") setter method which must be defined' in C:\OSPanel\domains\csmCrew_github\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php on line 1135**

I am trying to add SQL filter using [this DareDevels tutorial](https://daredevel.com/2013/05/setup-doctrine2-filters-in-zend-framework-2/#disqus_thread)

---

my interface: VacanciesFilterInterface.php

```
namespace Common\DoctrineFilter;

Interface  VacanciesFilterInterface
{
    public function setFilters($filters);
}
```

my filter class: VacanciesFilter.php

```
namespace Common\DoctrineFilter;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;

class VacanciesFilter extends SQLFilter
{
    /**
     * Gets the SQL query part to add to a query.
     *
     * @param ClassMetaData $targetEntity
     * @param string $targetTableAlias
     *
     * @return string The constraint SQL if there is available, empty string otherwise.
     */
    public function addFilterConstraint (ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {
        // Check if the entity implements the LocalAware interface
        if (!$targetEntity->reflClass->implementsInterface('\Common\DoctrineFilter\VacanciesFilterInterface')) {
            return '';
        }

        return $targetTableAlias.'.Vacancies = ' . $this->getParameter('Vacancies'); // getParameter applies quoting automatically
    }
```

my module.config.php:

```
'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            // defines an annotation driver with two paths, and names it `my_annotation_driver`
            'common_entity' => array(
                'class' => \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver::class,
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(
                    __DIR__ . '/../src/Common/Entity',
                    __DIR__ . '/../src/Common/Entity/Repository',
                ),
            ),

            // default metadata driver, aggregates all other drivers into a single one.
            // Override `orm_default` only if you know what you're doing
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    // register `my_annotation_driver` for any entity under namespace `My\Namespace`
                    'Common\Entity' => 'common_entity',
                ),
                'filters' => array(
                    'vacancies' => 'Common\DoctrineFilter\VacanciesFilter',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

I add filter in my controller using these methods:

```
public function enableVacanciesFilter()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $filter = $em->getFilters()->enable('vacancies');
        $filter->setParameter('vacancies', '41');
    }

    /**
     * Disable locale filter
     */
    public function disableVacanciesFilter()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $filter = $em->getFilters()->disable('vacancies');
    }
```

So the question is: how can I implement that callable setFilters setter method ?
I have tried to implement Interface in my Entity:

```
 <?php

namespace Common\Entity;

use Common\DoctrineFilter\VacanciesFilterInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Vacancies
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="vacancies", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="RankId_fk", columns={"rank_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="id", columns={"id"}), @ORM\Index(name="FK_vacancies_crewing_companies", columns={"company_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="FK_vacancies_vessels", columns={"vessel_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="FK_vacancies_vacancy_positions", columns={"position"}), @ORM\Index(name="status_id", columns={"status_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Vacancies implements VacanciesFilterInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="additional_info", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $additionalInfo = '';

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="duration_of_contract_in_months", type="smallint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $durationOfContractInMonths;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="joining_date", type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    private $joiningDate;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="salary_per_month", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $salaryPerMonth;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="required_age_from", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $requiredAgeFrom;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="required_age_to", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $requiredAgeTo;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="creation_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $creationDate;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="views_count", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $viewsCount = '0';

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="job_seekers_applied", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $jobSeekersApplied = '0';

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_published", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isPublished = '0';

    /**
     * @var \Common\Entity\CrewingCompanies
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Common\Entity\CrewingCompanies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @var \Common\Entity\VacancyPositions
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Common\Entity\VacancyPositions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="position", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @var \Common\Entity\Vessels
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Common\Entity\Vessels")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="vessel_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $vessel;

    /**
     * @var \Common\Entity\Ranks
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Common\Entity\Ranks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rank_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $rank;

    /**
     * @var \Common\Entity\VacancyStatuses
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Common\Entity\VacancyStatuses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="status_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $status;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set additionalInfo
     *
     * @param string $additionalInfo
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setAdditionalInfo($additionalInfo)
    {
        $this->additionalInfo = $additionalInfo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get additionalInfo
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdditionalInfo()
    {
        return $this->additionalInfo;
    }

    /**
     * Set durationOfContractInMonths
     *
     * @param integer $durationOfContractInMonths
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setDurationOfContractInMonths($durationOfContractInMonths)
    {
        $this->durationOfContractInMonths = $durationOfContractInMonths;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get durationOfContractInMonths
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getDurationOfContractInMonths()
    {
        return $this->durationOfContractInMonths;
    }

    /**
     * Set joiningDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $joiningDate
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setJoiningDate($joiningDate)
    {
        $this->joiningDate = $joiningDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get joiningDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getJoiningDate()
    {
        return $this->joiningDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set salaryPerMonth
     *
     * @param integer $salaryPerMonth
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setSalaryPerMonth($salaryPerMonth)
    {
        $this->salaryPerMonth = $salaryPerMonth;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salaryPerMonth
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getSalaryPerMonth()
    {
        return $this->salaryPerMonth;
    }

    /**
     * Set requiredAgeFrom
     *
     * @param boolean $requiredAgeFrom
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setRequiredAgeFrom($requiredAgeFrom)
    {
        $this->requiredAgeFrom = $requiredAgeFrom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get requiredAgeFrom
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getRequiredAgeFrom()
    {
        return $this->requiredAgeFrom;
    }

    /**
     * Set requiredAgeTo
     *
     * @param boolean $requiredAgeTo
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setRequiredAgeTo($requiredAgeTo)
    {
        $this->requiredAgeTo = $requiredAgeTo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get requiredAgeTo
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getRequiredAgeTo()
    {
        return $this->requiredAgeTo;
    }

    /**
     * Set creationDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $creationDate
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setCreationDate($creationDate)
    {
        $this->creationDate = $creationDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get creationDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreationDate()
    {
        return $this->creationDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set viewsCount
     *
     * @param integer $viewsCount
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setViewsCount($viewsCount)
    {
        $this->viewsCount = $viewsCount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get viewsCount
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getViewsCount()
    {
        return $this->viewsCount;
    }

    /**
     * Set jobSeekersApplied
     *
     * @param integer $jobSeekersApplied
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setJobSeekersApplied($jobSeekersApplied)
    {
        $this->jobSeekersApplied = $jobSeekersApplied;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get jobSeekersApplied
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getJobSeekersApplied()
    {
        return $this->jobSeekersApplied;
    }

    /**
     * Set isPublished
     *
     * @param boolean $isPublished
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setIsPublished($isPublished)
    {
        $this->isPublished = $isPublished;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isPublished
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsPublished()
    {
        return $this->isPublished;
    }

    /**
     * Set company
     *
     * @param \Common\Entity\CrewingCompanies $company
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setCompany(\Common\Entity\CrewingCompanies $company = null)
    {
        $this->company = $company;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get company
     *
     * @return \Common\Entity\CrewingCompanies
     */
    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    /**
     * Set position
     *
     * @param \Common\Entity\VacancyPositions $position
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setPosition(\Common\Entity\VacancyPositions $position = null)
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get position
     *
     * @return \Common\Entity\VacancyPositions
     */
    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    /**
     * Set vessel
     *
     * @param \Common\Entity\Vessels $vessel
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setVessel(\Common\Entity\Vessels $vessel = null)
    {
        $this->vessel = $vessel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vessel
     *
     * @return \Common\Entity\Vessels
     */
    public function getVessel()
    {
        return $this->vessel;
    }

    /**
     * Set rank
     *
     * @param \Common\Entity\Ranks $rank
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setRank(\Common\Entity\Ranks $rank = null)
    {
        $this->rank = $rank;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rank
     *
     * @return \Common\Entity\Ranks
     */
    public function getRank()
    {
        return $this->rank;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param \Common\Entity\VacancyStatuses $status
     *
     * @return Vacancies
     */
    public function setStatus(\Common\Entity\VacancyStatuses $status = null)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return \Common\Entity\VacancyStatuses
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setFilters ($filters)
    {
        $this->filters = $filters;
        // TODO: Implement setFilters() method.
    }
}
```

But nothing helps to deal with that error.